# how to make google web page tree view in google search?

Tags: google-app-engine, treeview, yahoo, bing

I'm looking for a code that Google or yahoo or bing or ... will automatically show web page tree view.

tree view of website it depends on sitemap, so, how can we set that Google will show website tree in Google search result, something like contact us page and other pages will appear in down of domain name that user will be able to click on those tree view links.

I really appropriate for your posts and comments about this issue.

Regards

Answer (score 3):

It's not totally up to you, Google will decide when and if they are going to show that and it's only for the top result. You should add your site to [Webmasters Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/) and you can read more about [Sitelinks](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en).